# XMLHttpRequest cannot load 'URL'. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, http-status-code-401, preflight

I work on ionic. and got this error. Here are my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('eMoMo', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
       //Reset headers to avoid OPTIONS request (aka preflight)
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {};
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post = {};
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.delete = {};
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put = {};
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
       $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';                                     
       //$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + btoa(my_id+ ':' + my_pass")
   }]);

app.controller('MainViewController',  function($scope, $http) {
  $http({
    method:"GET",
    url: "my_url"
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
        'authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('my_username' + ':' + 'my_pass')
        'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
    }
  }).then(function(categories){
    console.log(categories);
  });

});

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

)

I try to research, it is relate about CORS but I have install an plugin to chrome to disable that error. How can I solve this problem. ?

Comment: which version of chrome are you using? I reckon it might be 37 or 38?

Comment: @varit05 — What makes you think the OP is using such an ancient version of Chrome?

Comment: If I'm not wrong `401` is Unathorized, probably the OPTIONS call is handled but since it has no authorization header it's rejected, you should handle `OPTIONS` to return `200 OK`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding custom headers, you are triggering a [preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests). Your plugin, presumably, just sticks `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` onto ever response before Chrome processes it. That doesn't help when the server responds to the OPTIONS request with an error.

You have four options:

1. Make sure the server is on the same origin so you don't need CORS (this may involve setting up a development server that better reflects your live environment)
2. Get the server to support CORS
3. Find a plugin which can handle preflight requests (or fix your existing one so it can)
4. Change your code so it doesn't generate a preflight request

A starting point for option 4 would be to remove:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*';
```

and

```
'access-control-allow-origin': '*'
```

… since Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Headers are **response** headers and make no sense at all on a request.

You may still run into issues with your manual adding of an Authorization header though.

Answer (score -1):

generally 401 is related to an unauthorized request.

1. Pls verify your password and username,
2. if both are correct then the destiantion server doesnt accept btoa encoding of your username and passwoord. Try BaseConverter64 encoding

Comment: It doesn't matter what the credentials are, they won't be included in the preflight OPTIONS request that the browser makes to find out if it has permission to make the request with the credentials.

Comment: @Quentin: checking `preflight OPTIONS` is one approach to look at the problem. But the error speciafically says 401. Moreover if it was something related to `CORS` or `preflight OPTIONS` the error would have been different. makes sense???

Comment: No. The error would not have been different. The error explicitly says "Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401". It wouldn't say that if it wasn't talking about the response to the preflight OPTIONS request.